# Google App Engine Flexible Environment, Custom Runtime, general newbie questions

Tags: google-app-engine, docker

I want to build a web application using a mixture of App Engine Standard and Flexible Environment as described in the Google docs (flexible as microservice where third party software is needed, standard for everything else).

I need the mentioned microservice to run latex, a few linux tools and python. What is the best way to go from here?

My guess is:
Build a docker container from a Linux OS and use either Google Pub/Sub, Google Task Queue or plain HTTP for communication with the Standard Env App.

But how is this custom runtime then managed by Google regarding security updates, scaling, loadbalancing and everything else promised in the docs?

Sorry for the rather generic question, the infos are thin IMHO and so I have to ask.

Answer (score 3):

It would be your responsability to re-build the custom runtime images (done during every app deployment) to incorporate security updates. If your Dockerfile references other Google-supplied base images then the security updates for them will be automatically picked up in the process. But for any additional packages or customisations you added to your runtime you may need to incorporate the updates yourself.

Scaling depends on your app's configuration (your responsability), see [Service scaling settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#services).

Google automatically load-balances traffic across your app's instances.